# Using Hungarian algorithm when workers are in rank order

Tags: python, matching, hungarian-algorithm

I'm not sure if the application of the Hungarian Algorithm is correct in this situation. I need to assign a job to a ranked order list of employees (ordered by seniority) based on their preferences - where they have ranked every option.

So the most senior person gets their first choice, the second most senior person gets their first choice (unless already chosen then they get their second choice), the third most senior person gets their first choice (unless already chosen, then their second choice unless already chosen, then their third choice) and so on.

I've tried using what I think is just a general application of the Hungarian Algorithm where my selection matrix contains waited values of choices, but this doesn't seem to produce the desired result. Each row represents an employee and each column is the work assignment.

```
selection_matrix = [[1,2,3,4,5],[4,2,6,10,8],[3,9,15,12,6],[12,16,20,8,4],[15,5,20,10,25]]
```

Comment: "I've tried using what I think is just a general application of the Hungarian Algorithm"  you forgot to add that code in the question. You also need to provide what is the desired result and what is the result you are getting for an specific input, so we can see why the results differ

Comment: If you have an ordered list of employees, it will be much faster to just assign them their preferred job one-by-one, and then only use the Hungarian algorithm if more than one employee has the same rank (and use it only for those employees).